# How to re-execute scripts in re-rendered regions?

Tags: javascript, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I use richfaces / ajax4jsf to partially rerender regions of my page, here's a stripped down example:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="..." reRender="infoBlock" action="#{...}"/>
<h:panelGrid id="infoBlock">
  <h:outputText value="..."/>
  <f:verbatim>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log('test')
    </script>
  </f:verbatim>
</h:panelGrid>
```

My problem is, the script `console.log('test')` doesn't get reexecuted when the infoBlock is rerendered.

By the way, I'm aware that I could remove the script tag and use `oncomplete="console.log('test')"` in the above example. However, in the real application the script is more complex an rendered by a component I use, so changing this might be quite tricky.

So my question is: How to re-execute scripts in re-rendered regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example you provided does exactly what you ask. Every time you click the button - `test` text is written to console. That is out-of-the-box behavior in RichFaces - scripts in re-rendered region are re-evaluated.

Comment: I tried it again, no console log and even alert isn't working. But I'm using an old version of Ajax4jsf: 1.0.6. Maybe that's the problem? did they change this in newer releases / rich faces?

Answer (score 0):

Scripts should be static and the data they operate on dynamic, so don't try to do this. Instead, execute some callback that operates on some changed dynamic data when the region is re-rendered. You already have a mechanism for this: `oncomplete="rerendered('infoBlock')"`.

You will then have static code somewhere to read dynamic data and do something with it - the static code should not be embedded in script elements on the page:

```
function rerendered(regionName) {
   //Do something depending on regionName
}
```

As for why it's not working as is, we need go to a bit "lower" level.

A given script element object has a flag that tells if the contents have already been executed, when a script element is inserted to the main DOM tree, it is only executed if the flag is `false`.

When using `.innerHTML` or such, the script elements inside the html are not executed at all.

It seems either of the above mechanism is in use.

Comment: I get what you saying, but the script tag is rendered by a component I use and moving the code to the oncomplete event might be quite tricky. Secondly, the contents of the script tag change since they depend on properties of the backing bean.

Comment: @TimBüthe Sorry but I don't think you get it - move the code to a static JS file. If it needs to be dynamically generated, you are mixing static code with dynamic data which is what I am saying is bad. All you need in the `oncomplete` attribute is a single function call like I have shown that is never modified. Example: you generate dynamically something like `console.log("test")`. Only the string `"test"` is dynamic data while `console.log` is static code. They can and should be separated.

Comment: This is not possible, or at least much work. I use [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/) and the used component [inputCalendar](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_inputCalendar.html) renders HTML along with a script tag that contains 20 lines of dynamic JavaScript. To change that, I would have to rewrite the whole component. So I guess I look for some kind of workaround.